# Why is my average query showing incorrect values?

Tags: mysql

I asked a question a few hours ago that was marked as closed and referred me a link that did not clear up my confusion.

I am trying to query a sports database in MySQL to list the names of players who are above average age compared to their teammates. Ideally, I want to group by team, find the average of each team, and compare that to each respective player on that team.

My results from this query seem to be comparing players to the entire databases' average, rather than the average of the team. Can anyone correct my query or propose an alternate query to get the correct data? A friend of mine suggested perhaps using two copies of the tables, but that is beyond the scope of my limited MySQL skills.

My relational schema are as follows:

player(player_name, age, position)

plays_for (player_name, team_name)

```
SELECT player.player_name, player.age
FROM 
plays_for 
INNER JOIN player ON player.player_name=plays_for.player_name
WHERE (SELECT AVG(age) FROM player 
GROUP BY plays_for.team_name1)< player.age
```

Comment: Can you provide an example scheme dataset using a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) for this particular problem?

Comment: I think you need to drop the GROUP BY and use AND plays_for.teamName = player.teamName AND then you do the age comparsion. But we need some sample data to know how the tables look and how to perform the query

Comment: Your database allows one player to play for several teams. Is this desired? As to your query: the subquery has no `WHERE` clause to restrict it to the main query's team. Your `GROUP BY` is superfluous, because when looking at a `plays_for` row, `plays_for.team_name1` is just one value, so there are no different groups. (If you got more than one group, the query would raise an error, because you cannot compare multiple values with `<`. `GROUP BY` just doesn't make sense there.)

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE statement does not include the team grouping.  I personally like WITH statements which seems to be the direction your friend was going.

```
> WITH average_ages AS ( SELECT AVG(p.age) AS average_age, pf.team_name
> FROM player p join plays_for pf on p.player_name = pf.player_name
> GROUP BY pf.team_name) aa 
> SELECT player.player_name, player.age 
> FROM plays_for  
> INNER JOIN player ON player.player_name=plays_for.player_name 
> INNER JOIN average_ages ON plays_for.team_name = average_ages.team_name
> WHERE player.age > average_ages.average_age;
```

The WITH statement at the top creates a temporary table of average ages and then joins it to the plays_for table.

The first few rows of the entire SELECT query before the WHERE statement would look like this

```
Name   Age  Team   Average_age
Tara   51   KOs    25
Bomb   45   KOs    25
Jess   20   BES    30
Buster 40   BES    30
```